# Enable or Disable Form button in React based on condition

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and going through a course online. I came across this issue, where i wanted to enable or disable a button based on values present in the text field. If it is create/edit option then submit button should be disabled by default but if any value is entered or edited the submit button should be enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to enable or disable your button on condition base then all you have to do is add ternary operator in your jsx like this

```
  <button id='my_button' disabled ={(activityChanged)?true:false}>Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried. Created `const [activityChanged, setActivityChanged] = useState(false);` by keeping the initial value of `activityChanged` to `false`. And applied disabled attribute to the button as shown below.

```
<Button
          disabled={!activityChanged}
          loading={submitting}
          floated="right"
          positive
          type="submit"
          content="Submit"
        />
```

And updated the value of `activityChanged` on `onChange` event of text input as shown below

```
const handleInputChange = (
    event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
    setActivity({ ...activity, [name]: value });
    setActivityChanged(true)
  };
```

Below is the complete code:

```
import React, { FormEvent, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form, Segment } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { IActivity } from "../../../app/models/activity";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";

interface IProps {
  setEditMode: (editMode: boolean) => void;
  activity: IActivity;
  createActivity: (activity: IActivity) => void;
  editActivity: (activity: IActivity) => void;
  submitting: boolean;
}

const ActivityForm: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  setEditMode,
  activity: initialFormState,
  createActivity,
  editActivity,
  submitting,
}) => {
  const initializeForm = () => {
    if (initialFormState) {
      return initialFormState;
    } else {
      return {
        id: "",
        title: "",
        category: "",
        description: "",
        date: "",
        city: "",
        venue: "",
      };
    }
  };

  const [activity, setActivity] = useState<IActivity>(initializeForm);
  const [activityChanged, setActivityChanged] = useState(false);
  
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(activity);
    if (activity.id.length === 0) {
      let newActivity = {
        ...activity,
        id: uuid(),
      };
      createActivity(newActivity);
    } else {
      editActivity(activity);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (
    event: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = event.currentTarget;
    setActivity({ ...activity, [name]: value });
    setActivityChanged(true)
  };

  return (
    <Segment clearing>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Input
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          name="title"
          placeholder="Title"
          value={activity.title}
        />
        <Form.TextArea
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          name="description"
          rows={2}
          placeholder="Description"
          value={activity.description}
        />
        <Form.Input
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          name="category"
          placeholder="Category"
          value={activity.category}
        />
        <Form.Input
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          name="date"
          type="datetime-local"
          placeholder="Date"
          value={activity.date}
        />
        <Form.Input
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          name="city"
          placeholder="City"
          value={activity.city}
        />
        <Form.Input
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          name="venue"
          placeholder="Venue"
          value={activity.venue}
        />
        <Button
          disabled={!activityChanged}
          loading={submitting}
          floated="right"
          positive
          type="submit"
          content="Submit"
        />
        <Button
          onClick={() => setEditMode(false)}
          floated="right"
          type="button"
          content="Cancel"
        />
      </Form>
    </Segment>
  );
};

export default ActivityForm;
```